# Filter a text from a specific file and append the output to another file Linux

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed, grep

I am trying to append a text from a file to the another file in Linux using the grep command .

I have a file named "temp1buildVersion.properties" which contain the data
like

```
Project version: 1.0.5
```

also, I have another file named buildversion.properties which contain  data

```
VERSION_BUILD=
```

I want to fetch content from  temp1buildVersion.properties" after "Project version:"  and append it to an existing file named "buildversion.properties"

so that output of the buildversion.properties  will be

```
VERSION_BUILD=1.0.5
```

currently, I am doing using the grep command to fetch data and appending output to  file " buildversion.properties "

```
grep 'Project version: ' /tmp/tempbuildVersion.properties | cut -d\   -f3  >> /tmp/buildversion.properties
```

it comes in two-line  How can I append to the same line /or a specific line?

```
VERSION_BUILD =
1.0.5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option is using `sed` to append to the end of the line, e.g.

```
sed "/VERSION_BUILD/s/\$/$(grep 'Project version: ' /tmp/tempbuildVersion.properties | cut -d\   -f3)/" buildversion.properties
```

Above your command is simply placed as a command substituion in `sed "/VERSION_BUILD/s/\$/$(your_cmd)/" file`. You would add `sed -i` to update the file in place.

You can eliminate the pipeline and `cut` by simply using `awk` to isolate the version number and shorten the command a bit, e.g.

```
sed "/VERSION_BUILD/s/\$/$(awk '/^Project version:/{printf "%s", $NF; exit}' /tmp/tempbuildVersion.properties)/" buildversion.properties
```

Comment: Happy to help, good luck with your scripting!

Answer (score 3):

You may use this `awk`:

```sh
awk -F ': ' 'FNR==NR {ver=$2; next} /^VERSION_BUILD=/ {print $0 ver}' temp1buildVersion.properties buildversion.properties > _tmp && mv _tmp buildversion.properties

VERSION_BUILD=1.0.5
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply,  is there any way we can append to buildversion.properties file itself. currently it print value in console  .

Answer (score 0):

If `ed` is available/acceptable.

```
printf '%s\n' 'r temp1buildVersion.properties' 's/^Project version: //' '1,$j' ,p Q | ed -s buildversion.properties
```

Change `Q` to `w` if you're ok with the output and to edit the file `buildversion.properties`

The script.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

ed -s "$1" <<-EOF
  r $2
  s/^Project version: //
  1,\$j
  ,p
  Q
EOF
```

You can execute with the files as the arguments.

```
./myscript buildversion.properties temp1buildVersion.properties
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -i '/VERSION_BUILD=/{x;s/.*/cat fileVersion/e;x;G;s/\n.*:\s*//}' fileBuild
```

Process the build file until a match on a line `VERSION_BUILD=`.

Swap to the hold space and insert the version file line.

Append the line from the version file to the current line and using pattern matching manipulate the line into the desired format.